# Где и как правильно закрывать (и нужно ли) соединение с базой данных через PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Интересует вопрос подключения к базе данных через PDO в стиле ООП. Почитал много статей на Хабре и подобных источниках, возникли некоторые вопросы. 1. насколько важно явно закрывать соединения с базой данных, если не явно соединение закрывается. 2. Закрывать соединение нужно через метод **__destruct** или есть какие либо альтернативные методы. Буду рад любому ответу!

Comment: В мануале mysqli правда, а не PDO, написано следубющее: "*Открытые непостоянные соединения MySQL и наборы результатов автоматически закрываются при уничтожении их объектов. Явное закрытие открытых соединений и освобождение наборов результатов не обязательно. Однако рекомендуется закрыть соединение, как только скрипт завершит выполнение всех своих операций с базой данных, если ему ещё предстоит большая обработка после получения результатов.*" ......... ну и закрывать по сути после запроса надо, а не в destruct

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ниже описал ситуацию! Как корректнее?

Answer (score 0):

т.к. соединение с БД затратная операция, то то их количество лучше минимизировать и  в идеале делать вообще 1 открытие/закрытие за выполнение скрипта. Например можно создать класс "connect" в деструкт положить дисконект и сделать этот класс глобальным. В результате у вас не будет многократных подключений/отключений от БД.

Comment: Класс DB, по факту при создании объекта этого класса создается соединение. есть метод query, правильно ли я вас понял, что я могу после выполнения запроса(то есть после получение, обновлении, отправки данных) нужно в этом методе вызвать destruct? Или же просто после запроса обнулить или выполнить функцию unset переменной, содержащую объект подключения... Как правильно?

Comment: -в классе DB должен быть метод destruct, который разорвет соединение.
-за весь код класс DB инициализируется только 1 раз,
-там где нужно им пользоваться вы обьявляете через global $db; что будете пользоваться им,
-унсетить переменную не нужно, когда весь код закончит выполняться удалятся все переменные и произойдет дестракт